# Google maps saddr blank not working in iOS 8

Tags: google-maps, ios8

I've been loading a map by calling the url `comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=blahblahblah&directionsmode=driving`, and on versions prior to ios 8, leaving saddr blank results in directions from your current location to the destination. however, on iOS 8 its just blank, has anyone else experienced this or found a workaround?

Comment: This is no longer an issue with the most recent Google maps for iOS 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just noticed this too. My workaround is to use "Current+Location" or "My+location" as the value for saddr instead of leaving it blank:

```
comgooglemaps://?saddr=Current+Location&daddr=blahblahblah&directionsmode=driving
```

or

```
comgooglemaps://?saddr=My+location&daddr=blahblahblah&directionsmode=driving
```

This workaround also does the right thing in iOS7 if you need something backwards compatible.

The [documentation for the Google Maps URL Scheme](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme#directions) still says that leaving the saddr field blank should default to the current location, so either Google needs to update their doc or this is a bug.

UPDATE: There is a thread for this bug at [gmaps-api-issues](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7197) and apparently it has been fixed.